# iframe in parent as target of form

Tags: html

The target attribute of a form can accept an iframename as value.
Is it possible to pass an iframe which resides in the parent?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an iframe as the target for a form. That means, on submitting the form, the main page is not reloaded, but the form results are sent to the iframe instead. The form itself will stay, unchanged.